# Can you register your car in a different state from your residence?

Tags: united-states, car, california

If you move to California from Florida but cannot afford to register your car there (the engine has been modified), is it still possible to keep the car registered in Florida but obtain a California driver's license (or an i.d. card)?

Comment: I don't see how this is a personal finance question.

Comment: @BrenBarn Car registration is essentially a tax.  I'd say it is a personal finance question.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A61TjQnCIZQ

Comment: Military move? I know you can get exceptions for cases like that... not sure what other exceptions/restrictions apply

Comment: `Members of the Armed Forces/NATO and their families who are stationed in California are not required to get a California vehicle registration.` - [CA-DMV](https://www.dmv.org/ca-california/car-registration.php#-Military-Vehicle-Registration-in-California-)

Answer (score 8):

According to the [California DMV](http://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/detail/pubs/brochures/howto/htvr9):

> A vehicle must be registered in California if it is based in California or is primarily used on California highways (located or operated in this state for a greater amount of time than any other individual state during the registration period), even if registered to a nonresident owner (CVC §4000.4).

You can read the details on the DMV site about what counts as establishing residency, etc., but it is pretty clear that if you are permanently relocating to California and driving your car in California, your car needs to be registered in California.

Comment: Add exception for Military members: `Military service members and their families have slightly different rules for car registration depending on whether they are residents of California or not ... Members of the Armed Forces/NATO and their families who are stationed in California are not required to get a California vehicle registration. To legally drive in the state, military service members must:` [CA DMV](https://www.dmv.org/ca-california/car-registration.php#-Military-Vehicle-Registration-in-California-)

Comment: Also, interestingly, the answer to the actual question asked is that not only *can* you register a car in a state where you're not a resident, you may be required to do so if the car is primarily used in a different state. That seems to work against the OP's desired plan of action in this case, but it remains true (as this answer shows for CA) that it's where the car is used not the residence of the owner.

Comment: @Brick: That is true, although the meaning of "residency" is itself defined for different purposes by different organizations, so my guess is that if you spent enough time using your car in a certain area to have to register it there, you would be wise to check the residency requirements there, because spending so much time there (or, e.g., being employed there) might expose you to tax liability or other things that depend on reisdency.

Answer (score 4):

You need to register the car where it is garaged. The risk you take can be significant.

Some jurisdictions will drive through an apartment complex looking for out of state vehicles. They note them and then return 30 days later. If they find them again they write a ticket. They can then force you to register the vehicle. If they can determine how long you have been there they can also hit you with failure to pay any taxes associated with the vehicle in a timely manner. Failure to pay can result in additional penalties and interest. Some jurisdictions will tow and impound the vehicle, which can add additional fees and hassle.

Some people try to avoid the registration to save money on taxes, or they want to avoid an inspection that they know will find problems. Some get away with it for a while, but others get caught and owe thousands extra.